# Null values for system entities

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I tried an example in api.ai, with reference to the [Beginner's Guide](https://api.ai/docs/getting-started/building-your-first-agent), I am attaching error response as a screen-shot. I was expecting to get the values of marked intents.
[image]

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What are you expecting? Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: In the screenshot, values for the parameters are null. But in the example, it was returning values. please go through the link I provided. thanks for response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, somehow, you have "tomorrow" associated with a city entity in the first example phrase (the purple color matches the @sys:geo-city-gb entity). Because of this, it is looking for a phrase "Can I know available slots for *somewhere*" where the *somewhere* should be a city name. But "tomorrow" is not the name of a city, so it doesn't include that.

Since neither parameter is required, but it has a pretty close match, it is able to match the intent - but none of the parameters fit, so they're all left empty.

You should be able to delete this and re-type "tomorrow" to change it back to a @sys.date entity. Or add additional phrases which match it against a date.